# Unable to add Long values in Groovy

Tags: javascript, groovy, groovyscriptengine

Unable to add Long values in Groovy.
When we sum, it is not adding value after decimal.

```
  Long val1 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 1 Annual $'));
  Long val2 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 2 Annual $'));
  Long val3 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 3 Annual $'));
  Long val4 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 4 Annual $'));
  Long val5 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Estimated Development Cost $'));

  BigDecimal sum = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4) / val5 
  return sum.round(2);
```

When we sum = (2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5), getting 8. It should be 10

```
sum = (2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5 + 2.5) / 3
```

Getting 2.67, it should be 3.33

when we sum, it is not adding value after decimal.
getting 8, it should be 10

Comment: I wonder what you expected from Long....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype `Long` truncates `2.5` into `2`, resulting in `2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 8`.

Try storing your values in `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal val1 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 1 Annual $'));
BigDecimal val2 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 2 Annual $'));
BigDecimal val3 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 3 Annual $'));
BigDecimal val4 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Benefit 4 Annual $'));
BigDecimal val5 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue('Estimated Development Cost $'));
```

I would also suggest using `add` and `divide` since this way you gain more control over precision and rounding:

```
BigDecimal sum = val1.add(val2).add(val3).add(val4).divide(val5, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Isn't BigDecimal an overkill for this? A simple `double` would do the job right?

Comment: When dealing with monetary values, it is generally recommended to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` to avoid precision errors that may arise due to the binary representation of floating-point numbers.

Comment: I used Long while storing the value because of there are some values in millions will it store those values too...?

Comment: `Long` only goes until 64-bit, `BigDecimal` follows arbitrary precision and will get as large as possible until your computer runs out of memory. In general you can store much higher values than just a few millions when using `BigDecimal`.